# code snippet list python easiert form

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

How do I write this code snippets easier or in one line?

```
dist=[]
for k in range(5):
    dist.append(k)
dist[0]="Apple"
print(dist)
```

Comment: you can also type it I guess.. Like literally do `dist = ['Apple', 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: A compromise between the clever answers and your more explicit code is to just do the first three lines in one, and leave the explicit fourth line in: `dist=list(range(5))`. I only mention this to give a bit of depth; I think Uriel's answer is best.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> dist = ['Apple', *range(1, 5)]
>>> dist
['Apple', 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.7 (works in Python 3+ as well):

```
>>> dist = ['Apple'] + [i for i in range(1,5)]
>>> dist
['Apple', 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: In Python 2.x `range()` returns a list, so you can directly do `['Apple'] + range(1, 5)`. Or for slightly shorter / more effiicent code that works on both Python 2 and 3, `['Apple'] + list(range(1, 5))`.